# Regex for string not ending with given suffix in teradata query

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to fetch the rows from database where it start with a quote sign and do not end with quote sign. I have rows as follows in the Name column,

```
"TEXT
"TEXT"
"TEST
"TEST"
```

Desired output from select query,

```
"TEXT
"TEST
```

SQL query,

```
SELECT * FROM db.supplier where  regexp_instr(Name_ ,'^[\"][\w-_.]+(?<!")') = 1;
```

I know the regex should be ending with $ to mark the end but it also didn't worked. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `like`?

```
where Name_ like '"%' and Name_ not like '%"'
```

That seems simple enough.  You could also use `regexp_similar()`:

```
where regexp_similar(Name_, '^".*[^"]$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a negative lookbehind? This will return any values which start, but don't end with a double quote:

```
where regexp_similar(Name_ ,'".+[^"]') = 1
```